Why can't I get the Timestamp of the date '1914-11-08 00:00:00' in timezone 'Europe/Amsterdam'?
Recently i upgraded my mysql-connector from 5.1.47 to 8.0.33. After that, i met an error:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:90) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:74) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:85) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:947) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:985) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getTimestamp(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.Loadable.hydrate(Loadable.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    ... 113 common frames omitted

By investigating this error, I got that the new mysql driver would do some converting and my dataset contains the date '1916-05-01 00:00 00'. According to wikipedia, the first nation-wide daylight saving time implementations were by the German and Austro-Hungarian Empires, both starting on 30 April 1916. So it may be thinking that it can't convert '1916-05-01 00:00 00' to timestamp since '1916-05-01 00:00 00' is 'non-existent', only '1916-05-01 01:00 00'.
I decided to find out all of these 'non-existent' dates in timezone 'Europe/Amsterdam'. Here is how i did:
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
        start.setTime(sdf.parse("1900-01-01"));
        end.setTime(sdf.parse("2025-01-01"));
        List<String> errorItems = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!start.after(end)) {
            try {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"), Locale.US);
                calendar.setLenient(false);
                calendar.set(start.get(Calendar.YEAR), start.get(Calendar.MONTH), start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);
                Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                System.out.println(ts);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                errorItems.add(sdf.format(start.getTime()));
            }
            start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
        System.out.println("error date: " + errorItems);
    }

The result is: [1914-11-08, 1916-05-01]
The '1916-05-01' I've already understood, but why '1914-11-08'? The DST even did not exist in 1914. Does anyone have any idea?
I'd like to know why I can't get the Timestamp of the date '1914-11-08 00:00:00' in timezone 'Europe/Amsterdam'.

Can you switch to using the newer java.time classes instead? The ones you are using are full of bugs and outdated.

I know changing to java.time classes can solve this, but it would be a huge pain to do that as it's a old app and we have some other logic entangled with this. I just don't understand why this '1914-11-08 00:00:00' can't be handled. There was no DST in 1914 so '1914-11-08 00:00:00' should be a valid time

'TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html did you mean datetime?

I mean java.sql.Timestamp. even if a time before '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC can be converted to  a java.sql.Timestamp value, right? @P.Salmon

I have reproduced. My output is error date: [1914-11-08, 1916-05-01].

My Java 19 believes that that day started at 1914-11-08T01:00+01:00[Europe/Amsterdam]. timeanddate.com disagrees.

there is not only "daylight saving time" - from the Time Zone Database data: "*#   In early November 1914, the Germans imposed the time zone used in central
Europe and forced the inhabitants to set their watches and public clocks
sixty minutes ahead.*" (corresponding data)

If you can solve this problem using Instant or OffsetDateTime from java.time, I suggest that it is more than worth it. It doesn’t necessarily mean changing all date and time code in your Java source files. For interoperating with old code easy conversion methods exist.

About two years ago the maintainers of the IANA time zone database decided that since Brussels and Amsterdam have identical time zone rules starting from 1970, that they would "link" Europe/Amsterdam to Europe/Brussels.  This effectively erased the pre-1970 history of time zone rules for Europe/Amsterdam, and substitutes in the pre-1970 rules Europe/Brussels.
For Europe/Brussels the local date 1914-11-08 00:00:00 does not exist because at that time, local time jumped ahead by one hour to 1914-11-08 01:00:00.  This change was not true for Amsterdam.
Your upgrade from 5.1.47 to 8.0.33 apparently picked up this change in the IANA tz database.

PS:  If you don't like this change to the IANA tz database, don't take it out on me.  I'm just the messenger.
